# Insert into if exists update pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, database, screen-scraping

I'm trying to insert data from a dataframe into SQL Server with pyodbc in jupyter notebook. I want the the data to update every month. How do I type it like if_exists=replace? BTW I must only use pyodbc bcs sqlachemy didn't work for me. Thank you in advance!

```
import pyodbc 
# Some other example server values are
# server = 'localhost\sqlexpress' # for a named instance
# server = 'myserver,port' # to specify an alternate port
server = '10.10.2.44' 
Trusted_Connection='yes'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password +';Trusted='+Trusted_Connection)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
col_names = ["month", "average", "min", "max", "nb_working_days"]
df = pd.read_csv("data_usd.csv",sep=',',quotechar='\'',encoding='utf8', names=col_names,skiprows = 1) # Replace Excel_file_name with your excel sheet name
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    cursor.execute('UPDATE INTO dbo.data_usd([month],[average],[min],[max],[nb_working_days]) values (?,?,?,?,?)', 
                    row['month'], 
                    row['average'], 
                    row['min'],
                    row['max'],
                    row['nb_working_days'] )
                    
    cnxn.commit()
cursor.close()
cnxn.close()
```

Comment: See [@AaronBertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2020/09/locking/upsert-anti-pattern) for best practice for Upsert (Insert/Update) operations. By the way, I'd love to know how you think the username and password are being used when `Trusted_connection=yes`

Comment: sorry im very new to all this thing! thank you anyway